# mysql query for a matrix

Tags: mysql, matrix

I have some data from an evaluation. Possible values are (1,2,3,4,5) and are stored in a table, for each question 1 column.

Table evaluation:

```
f1 f2 q3 ...
1  5  2
2  4  3
.
.
.
```

I want to generate for 2 columns 1 matrix:

```
How often is f1=1 when q3=1?
How often is f1=1 when q3=2?
...
How often is f1=5 when q3=5?
```

So it will be in my case a 5*5 matrix.
How can I solve this with mysql properly?

My first (working) attempt is to brute force it with 25 unions like:

```
SELECT count(0) FROM evaluation where q3 = 1 and f2 = 1
union all
SELECT count(0) FROM evaluation where q3 = 1 and f2 = 2
union all
...
union all
SELECT count(0) FROM evaluation where q3 = 5 and f2 = 5
```

But how can it be done in a nice way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT f1, count(f1), f3
FROM evaluation
GROUP BY f3, f1
```

would give you the f1 counts for all values of f3.

Comment: Thats's nearly the perfect query, wow. The only point is now, that i need to fill out the "no-matches" with zeros. Ill try to find a solution.
Would it also be possible to get the result not in a list, rather in a table-like view?

Comment: that kind of transformation is best done client-side. sql is more for fetching data. formatting/display isn't what the DB is for.